# Easily switch between stack snippet view and question view

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I love stack snippets.  But the problem with stack snippets is that if I am working on the snippet, I can't see the question I'm answering.

Currently there are two options for referring back to the question (or material I've already written in an answer):

- Click "Insert into post" on my half-finished code, double-check/copy/change whatever I need to do on the main page, then scroll down to the compiled preview of my snippet and click the Edit button to re-open it.  And then do it all over again next time I need to check or change something.
- Open the question again in a separate tab of the browser.  Much more functional, but still not ideal.  And it doesn't work for going back to the answer I'm half-finished writing.

It would be nice to have a more convenient way to minimize the modal and then open it up again.

Comment: I just suggested to an answerer that he post a stack snippet instead of a link to jsfiddle. The reason he gave for not using snippets was that it was hard to go back and forth.